# Name of a property of characteristic functions (Fourier transforms)

Tags: terminology, characteristic-function

I'm a scientist but not a professional mathematician and in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4663958/possible-typo-in-a-text-using-fourier-transform-properties/4663990), I asked about a possible typographical error in an [article on round-off error](https://doi.org/10.1021/ac50057a033) that I've been reading in the journal *Analytical Chemistry*.
The results presented in that article are said to rely on three properties of [characteristic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) (cf). Specifically, the paper says (column 1, p. 1142) the following (in which I have corrected the typo).

> Three general properties of characteristic functions are:
> (1) If $g_1$ is the c.f. of $f_1$ and $g_2$ is the c.f. of $f_2$ then $g_1 - g_2$ is the c.f. of $f_1 - f_2$.
> (2) If $g(t)$ is the c.f. of $f(z)$ and $z$ is displaced by the fixed value $z_0$ so that the PDF is $f(z-z_0)$, the c.f. of $f(z-z_0)$ is $g(t)\, \mathrm{exp}(i z_0 t).$
> (3) If $g(t)$ is the c.f. of $f(z)$, then the  the c.f. of $\int_{-\infty}^z f(w)\,\mathrm dw$ is $-g(t)/(it)$.

Are there ***well recognized names*** for each of the listed properties?

Comment: (1) and (3) should be really considered as properties of Fourier transform, not characteristic functions,  as they apply to functions that are not probability distributions (such as $f_1-f_2$).  The first one follows from *linearity*, I doubt if the other two have specific names

Comment: I spent years in graduate school studing FTs and their generalizations, but do not recall any special terms for (2) or (3).  I always explained (and thought of) (3) as "the FT interconverts differentiation and multiplication [by the variable]."  Both of these are linear operators on appropriate function spaces.